# Images not loading from Theme in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am running CakePHP 2.3.1. I have created my `app/View/Themed/my_theme` directory as required. I have added the `webroot` directory to the theme where I have put all of my theme assets. However, images are not being loaded when I use `$this->Html->image('{some_image}');`.

Do I need to stage the images in a different directory? If I put them in the main app/webroot/img directory, of course they appear on the page as expected.

*Update:*
Using the example of `logo.png` I have the following:

Images are staged here: `app/View/Themed/{my_theme}/webroot/img/logo.png`

The images are not showing up on the rendered page. The source of the image is showing up as: `<img src="http://example.com/img/logo.png">`

Comment: what is the generated url of those images?

Comment: They come back as `http://domain/img/some_image`

Comment: So the urls are right then?

Comment: They are generated correctly, but the location is wrong as the img does not sit in `app/webroot/img`, it is in `app/View/Themed/my_theme/webroot/img`, so the image is not appearing on the page.

Comment: The you cant use `$this->Html->image('{some_image}');`

Comment: Did you try `/my_theme/img/logo.png` - maybe you also need the AssetDispatcher

Comment: I just tried `/my_theme/img/logo.png` and it didn't work. I also confirmed the AssetDispatcher is in place.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need the AssetDispatcher in your bootstrap:

```
Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters', array(
    'AssetDispatcher'
));
```

This will make it possible to use plugin or theme assets.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html#configuring-filters

Comment: I am showing that the dispatcher is already in the bootstrap. `Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters', array(
 'AssetDispatcher',
 'CacheDispatcher'
));`